# UISwitch in a table selects multiple cells when switch state on

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom cell in my Swift 4 project that includes a switch.  When I select any switch I selects every 10th switch in the table. There are 34 cells in the table.  I have tried many different combinations of user interaction enabled/disabled. Even though the state of the non-selected switches show as "on", the associated actions don't fire off. Here is the code that fires off the action:

```
@IBAction func SwitchAction(_ sender: UISwitch ) {

    let switchPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint(), to:tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at:switchPosition)
    let ipath = indexPath?.row
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return taskList.count

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let cell: customTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! customTableViewCell
    cell.LabelSelect.text=taskList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does your switch action give you the correct index?

Comment: add target to switch in cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: addTarget is giving an error in Swift 4

Comment: I have split the tables into 6 different view controllers. That seems to fix the error. Apparently having more than 10 cells in the table is causing issues. Not sure where the argument of 10 is coming from ... bug in S4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to cells being re-used.  When you scroll the tableView, some rows go off screen; the associated cells are placed into a queue.  Other rows appear on screen; the `cellForRowAt` method is called and takes a cell from the queue (hence `dequeueReusableCell`), to be used for the new row.  If the switch was on when the cell went off screen, it will still be on when it appears on screen - even though it now relates to a completely different row.

The solution is to maintain an array which indicates whether the switch for a given row should be on or off.  Then you can use that array to correctly set the switch on or off in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: That makes total sense.  Thank you!